# Android Adapter throw IndexOutOfBoundsException while scrolling

Tags: android, listadapter

From firbase, I saw a lot of crash logs:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Invalid index 7, size is 0
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException (ArrayList.java:255)
java.util.ArrayList.get (ArrayList.java:308)
com.weex.app.adapters.CartoonReaderAdapter.getItemViewType (CartoonReaderAdapter.java:357)
android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.getScrapView (AbsListView.java:7132)
android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView (AbsListView.java:2469)
android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView (ListView.java:1920)
android.widget.ListView.fillUp (ListView.java:751)
android.widget.ListView.fillGap (ListView.java:690)
android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll (AbsListView.java:5579)
android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded (AbsListView.java:3641)
android.widget.AbsListView.startScrollIfNeeded (AbsListView.java:3569)
android.widget.AbsListView.onInterceptTouchEvent (AbsListView.java:4711)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2157)
```

it seems `adapter.getItemViewType` throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` while flinging. I've checked my code, all `notifyDataSetChanged` is  called in main thread. Here is my adapter code:

```
@Override
  public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    Log.e("TAG","notify data change:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    rebuildViewTypes();
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return viewTypes == null ? 0 : viewTypes.size();
  }

  private void rebuildViewTypes() {
    viewTypes.clear();
    if (pictures == null || pictures.size() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    CartoonReaderTypeItem item = null;

    if (topGap > 0) {
      item = new CartoonReaderTypeItem();
      item.type = LIST_ITEM_TYPE_GAP;
      viewTypes.add(item);
    }

    if (topHint != null) {
      item = new CartoonReaderTypeItem();
      item.type = LIST_ITEM_TYPE_TOP_HINT;
      viewTypes.add(item);
    }

    if (pictures != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < pictures.size(); i++) {
        PictureItem pictureItem = pictures.get(i);
        item = new CartoonReaderTypeItem();
        item.type = LIST_ITEM_TYPE_PICTURE;
        item.item = pictureItem;
        viewTypes.add(item);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    CartoonReaderTypeItem item = viewTypes.get(position);
    return item.item;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 16;
  }

  /**
   * @param position
   * @return
   */
  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    CartoonReaderTypeItem item = viewTypes.get(position);
    return item.type;
  }
```

I'm confused. All the methods(`dispatchTouchEvent`& `notifyDataSetChanged`) should be called in main thread. So there's not thread safety problem. The `viewTypes` data may be safe. The `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is beyond my understanding.

Any idea please?

Comment: Take a look on getCount() and getViewTypeCount(). Is there any relation?

Comment: in my adapter, the count of viewType isn't more than 16. So getViewTypeCount() return 16.

Comment: Provide proper code of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Index is starting with 0. In below code your position might be +1 higher than index of the array. So please check the position value.

```
    public int getItemViewType(int position) 
    {
           CartoonReaderTypeItem item = viewTypes.get(position);
           return item.type;
    }
```

Comment: Why? position should also start with 0.And the crash log doesn't match your comment:

```Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Invalid index 7, size is 0```

Answer (score 0):

try this might help -

```
 @Override
 public int getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
  }

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
 return viewTypes.size();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean:```getViewTypeCount()``` impact ```getItemViewType()```?